# msft c unresolved external tying to use dll function in win32 console app

Tags: visual-c++, unresolved-external

I have a very simple c++ dll that adds two numbers.  The source file looks like:

```
extern "C" {
__declspec(dllexport) double __stdcall myadder(double a,double a)
{
    return (a+b);
}
}
```

with a def file:

```
LIBRARY myadder
EXPORTS
    _myadder@16
```

The code of the exe is:

```
#include "stdio.h"

__ declspec(dllimport) double myadder(double a, double b);


int main()
{
double r;

r=myadder(5,6);

printf("myadder = %f \n",r);


return 0;
}
```

and I tell it to use myadder.lib qualified with the path to it.  but I get the error:

```
1>helloworld.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__myadder referenced in function _main
```

1>C:\lotus\optfunc\helloworld\Debug\helloworld.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

and if I get rid of the __declspec(dllimport) I instead get:

```
1>helloworld.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _myadder referenced in function _main
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You don't seem to be linking the EXE with the import library for the DLL.

Comment: @igor tandetnik I tell it to use myadder.lib

Comment: Mismatched calling convention. You make it `__stdcall` in the DLL, but the default (usually `__cdecl`) in the EXE.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik   Bingo! Thanks so much! How do I mark that as an answer?